# Get a RKMappingOperation from path

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm receiving objects on a web socket and I want to map them with object mappers that I have registered for the same REST service. The socket packet has a path component which corresponds to the resource path of the REST API so I would like to use that to retrieve either the mapping or the mapping operation itself.

How can I get a RKEntityMapping or RKMappingOperation from a path which I have previously registered with the object manager?

Comment: That isn't what the object manager is for. You're better off using a dictionary (keys are the paths) or something like that.

Comment: But I should be able to get a response mapping operation from a route (path) right?

Comment: Routes are for requests, you can't really get to a mapping or operation from there. The object manager works at a higher level, hiding all of the mapping stuff internally.

Comment: But if I get hold of the request then I should be able to get the response mapper for the requests response right? Can't I use that to map my own dictionary which I received on the web socket?

Comment: Do you see an API that offers you that functionality? Why are you sure you should be able to do it?

Comment: If RestKit is able to turn a json dictionary (from a response) to an object internally it just seems as I should be able to provide a json dictionary and let RestKit perform the same mapping operation on it. I'm not asking if it is intended to be used that way, just if it is possible and if so how it could be done

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but neither a router or a request is involved in that process. Well, the request URL is used, because that is the same as the response URL, and that's what maps to the response descriptor and thus the mapping. Hence I suggested using the path as the key in a dictionary to get to the mapping that should be used.

Comment: ok and how do I get the response descriptor with my custom dictionary? Specifically, which API method do I call?

Comment: You don't need a response descriptor, just create mappings and put them in the dictionary, then get them out again using the path and create the mapper operations and run them.